# Unable to add checkboxes to filter area

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add filter options to my filter area but have been unsuccessful so far. Text appears just fine, but things like text boxes, radio boxes, buttons, etc aren't appearing for some reason. Probably a simple fix, but I'm very new to CSS, HTML and design in general. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppr6a.jpg

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
    <title>Some Web Page</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='menu-container'>
      <div class='menu'>
        <div class='links'>
          <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
          <div class='login'>Login</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='header-container'>
      <div class='header'>
        <div class='logo'><img src='images/postloco.svg'/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <main>
      <input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle">
          <div class="filterbutton"><img src='images/filterbutton.svg'/></div>
      </label>
      <div id="expand">
        <section class="Filter">
            <h2>Text field</h2>
            <p>The <strong>input type="text"</strong> defines a one-line text input field:</p>

            <form action="/action_page.php">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit">
            </form>

            <p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>
            <p>Also note that the default width of a text field is 20 characters.</p>
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
    <section class="carousel">
    </section>
  </body>
  <footer>
      <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook" title="facebook" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter" title="twitter" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" href="#" class="social">
      <img src="images/snapchat.svg" alt="snapchat" title="snapchat" href="#" class="social">
      <ul>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">About</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Contact</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Team</a>
          <a alt="about" title="About" href="#" class="footerlink">Whatever</a>
      </ul>
  </footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-container {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #A34F43;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.login {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: #FF7C69;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel-grid {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  background: #FF7C69;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  /* display: block; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
label:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#expand {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background-color: #D6DBED;
  color: black;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #expand {
  height: 250px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #A34F43;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  /* display: flex; */
}

.footerlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
}

.social {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

.social:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

legend {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
  font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin: .4rem;
}

.filterbutton {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css you have this line that is hiding all form inputs

```
input {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I don't think you want to globally hide all inputs like this. If you need to hide certain input items you can group them either by css or by putting them in special HTML tags (divs for instance)
I see that you are having your main form expand after clicking a checkbox. In this case things should still work after removing the line above.